# How do you impl Borrow for a struct without making a dangling reference?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, PartialEq, Serialize)]
pub struct BookstoreRecord {
    pub _id: String,
    pub data: Bookstore,
}

impl Borrow<Document> for BookstoreRecord {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Document {
        let doc = doc! {
            "_id": self._id.clone(),
            "data": to_document(&self.data).unwrap(),
        };
        &doc
    }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler complains that we cannot return reference to local variable `doc` since it returns a reference to data owned by the current function

Comment: You don't. Either store the document in the type or don't implement `Borrow`.

Comment: This looks like a misuse of the `Borrow` trait, please [read the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) for considerations for using and implementing it.

Comment: It looks like you want to `impl Into<Document> for &BookstoreRecord` rather than implementing `Borrow`…

Comment: @Jmb `Into` should hardly ever be implemented directly. It's preferable to implement `From` instead, which gives `Into` for free. It's also rather uncommon to implement conversions for a reference type. In this particular case, I'd personally go with a simple inherent method `fn to_document(&self) -> bson::Result<Document>`, which has the additional advantage of passing on any serialization errors. (`TryFrom` would work as well, but I don't see any advantage for this case.)